# Matlab: Series of Variables in a Loop

Tags: matlab, variables, loops

This is a solution from another stackoverflow participant who helped me out.
Data is coming from a csv file:

```
    States Damage Blizzards

    Indiana 1      3
    Alabama 2      3
    Ohio    3      2
    Alabama 4      2


%// Parse CSV file
[States, Damage, Blizzards] = textread(csvfilename, '%s %d %d', ...
    'delimiter', ',', 'headerlines', 1);

%// Parse data and store in an array of structs
[U, ix, iu] = unique(States);        %// Find unique state names
S = struct('state', U);              %// Create a struct for each state
for k = 1:numel(U)
    idx = (iu == k);                 %// Indices of rows matching current state
    S(k).damage = Damage(idx);       %// Add damage information
    S(k).blizzards = Blizzards(idx); %// Add blizards information
end
```

In MATLAB, I need to create a series of assigned variables (A1,A2,A3) in a loop. So I have structure S with 3 fields: state, tornado, hurricane.

Now I have attempted this method to assign A1 =, A2 =, which I got an error because it will not work for structures:

```
   for n = 1:numel(S)
   eval(sprintf('A%d = [1:n]',S(n).states));
   end
```

Output goal is a series of assigned variables in the loop to the fields of the structure:

```
  A1 = 2 3
  A2 = 2 3
  A3 = 4 5
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the 'Matlab-way' of doing things, as explained [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/143)

Comment: @user1608954 Why do you need a bunch of variables with different names? Why not create another field in the structure for that, or at least use [cell arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html)?

Comment: Well, I'm generating a different variable name so I can plot the different variables.  Schorsch, here is a structure:    S = struct('Texas', 0, 'Kansas', 1, 'Maryland', 2)

Comment: I will.  Give me a minute.

Comment: I have posted the entire code.

Comment: You first block doesn't define any field called `S(foo).states`, yet you seem to have one.  Does the "struct" built-in defien a field called `state` (it's been years since I've used it).

Comment: Avoid creating A1, A2 ... in a loop and store it instead in a structure or a cell array. Why? Well you aready have problems sorting out a simple assignment like this with `eval()`, think when you'll have to perform something more complicated. It will be unreadable prone to errors and horrors of all sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your question.
But maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
for n = 1:numel(S)
   eval(sprintf('A%d = [S(n).damage S(n).blizzards]',n));
end
```

BTW using `evalc` instead of `eval` will suppress the command line output.

A little explanation, why

```
eval(sprintf('A%d = [1:n]',S(n).state));
```

does not work:

```
S(1).state
```

returns

```
ans = 
   Alabama
```

which is a string. However,

```
A%d
```

expects a number (see [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/formatting-strings.html#bq0hr54) for number formatting).
Additionally,

```
numel(S)
```

yields

```
ans = 
   3
```

Therefore,

```
eval(sprintf('A%d = [1:n]',n));
```

will simply return the following output:

```
A1 =

 1

A2 =

 1     2

A3 =

 1     2     3
```

Hence, you want `n` as a counter for the variable name, but compose the vector of the entries in the other struct-fields (`damage` and `blizzards`), again, using `n` as a counter.

Comment: THAT'S IT.  Thanks, Schorsch.  I had been working with something similar, but just couldn't complete it.  Thanks a lot.